# trouble of passing character into function as argument

Tags: r

I have the following code of a for loop in R. I want to call the name of each column and use it as an argument for the ggplot. The code I have here which is a for loop can only pass i as character into aes. However aes cannot take character as an argument.
Any thoughts?
`

```
for (i in names(data)){
    dev.new()
    p<- ggplot(data = data,aes(x=Name,y=i,color=group))+geom_line()
    ggsave(filename = as.character(paste(i,'.pdf')),plot = p)
    dev.off()
    }
```

`

Comment: Try `aes_string()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main options I can think of:

1. Make ggplot treat the strings as the column name by using `aes_string`. Don't forget to add quotes to your other variables for it to work

`p<- ggplot(data = data,aes_string(x="Name",y=i,color="group"))+geom_line()`

2. Supply the y column directly by using `data[,i]`:

`p<- ggplot(data = data,aes_string(x=Name,y=data[,i],color=group))+geom_line()`

I prefer the first option, as if you later on change your code to filter data (e.g. `ggplot(data=data[data[,i]>100,]...`), you will need to repeat the filter for `y` values.

Comment: No problem. I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers